# open_spider method run two times when using CrawlerProcess

Tags: python, scrapy, pymongo

I want to run multiple spiders, so i try to use `CrawlerProcess`. But i find the method `open_spider` will run two times at the beginning and the end with `process_item` method.

It causes when the spider open , i remove my collection and save the data into mongodb completed. It will remove my collection again finally.

How do i fix the issue and why the method `open_spider` run two times ?

I tyep `scrapy crawl movies` run the project:

Here is my movies.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
import time

# scrapy api imports
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

from Tainan.FirstSpider import FirstSpider

class MoviesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'movies'
    allowed_domains = ['tw.movies.yahoo.com', 'movies.yahoo.com.tw']
    start_urls = ['http://tw.movies.yahoo.com/movie_thisweek.html/']

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

process.crawl(FirstSpider)
process.start()
```

It's my FirstSpider.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request


class FirstSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'first'
    allowed_domains = ['tw.movies.yahoo.com', 'movies.yahoo.com.tw']
    start_urls = ['http://tw.movies.yahoo.com/movie_thisweek.html/']

    def parse(self, response):
        movieHrefs = response.xpath('//*[@class="release_movie_name"]/a/@href').extract()       
        for movieHref in movieHrefs:
            yield Request(movieHref, callback=self.parse_page)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        print 'FirstSpider => parse_page'
        movieImage = response.xpath('//*[@class="foto"]/img/@src').extract()
        cnName = response.xpath('//*[@class="movie_intro_info_r"]/h1/text()').extract()
        enName = response.xpath('//*[@class="movie_intro_info_r"]/h3/text()').extract()
        movieDate = response.xpath('//*[@class="movie_intro_info_r"]/span/text()')[0].extract()
        movieTime = response.xpath('//*[@class="movie_intro_info_r"]/span/text()')[1].extract()
        imdbScore = response.xpath('//*[@class="movie_intro_info_r"]/span/text()')[3].extract()
        movieContent = response.xpath('//*[@class="gray_infobox_inner"]/span/text()').extract_first().strip()
        yield {'image': movieImage, 'cnName': cnName, 'enName': enName, 'movieDate': movieDate, 'movieTime': movieTime, 'imdbScore': imdbScore, 'movieContent': movieContent}
```

It's my pipelines.py:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from scrapy.conf import settings

class MongoDBPipeline(object):

    global open_count
    open_count = 1
    global process_count
    process_count = 1

    def __init__(self):
        connection = MongoClient(
            settings['MONGODB_SERVER'],
            settings['MONGODB_PORT'])
        db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DB']]
        self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]
    # My issue is here it will print open_spider count = 2 finally.
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        global open_count
        print 'Pipelines => open_spider count =>'
        print open_count
        open_count += 1
        self.collection.remove({})
    # open_spider method call first time and process_item save data to my mongodb.
    # but when process_item completed, open_spider method run again...it cause my data that i have saved it has been removed.
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        global process_count
        print 'Pipelines => process_item count =>'
        print process_count
        process_count += 1
        self.collection.insert(dict(item))
        return item
```

I can't figure it out, some one can help me out that would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do i fix the issue and why the method `open_spider` run two times ?

The `open_spider` method runs once per spider, and you're running two spiders.

> I tyep `scrapy crawl movies` run the project

The `crawl` command will run the spider named `movies` (`MoviesSpider`).
To do this, it has to import the `movies` module, which will cause it to run your `FirstSpider` as well.

Now, how to fix this depends on what you want to do.
Maybe you should only run a single spider, or have separate settings per spider, or maybe something entirely different.

Comment: But i don't `yield` any data in movies.py , i just `yield` it in FirstSpider.py. I think it should be run `open_spider` method once.

Comment: Yielding data doesn't matter. `open_spider` is called when the spider is started, before scrapy knows if it will return any items. Why do you run the movies spider if you don't want it to do anything?

Comment: So i run two spiders make `open_spider` run two times i get it now !  Thank you very much !